# Using docker-compose to deploy docker containers in production

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created the following docker-compose.yml file to build docker containers for a Django application:

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    env_file:
      - .env_prod_db
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - net
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "10m"

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env_prod_web
    command: gunicorn roster_project.wsgi:application --disable-redirect-access-to-syslog --error-logfile '-' --access-logfile '-' --access-logformat '%(t)s [GUNICORN] %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"' --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static:/roster/webserver/static/
    networks:
      - net
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "10m"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static:/roster/webserver/static/
    networks:
      - net
    depends_on:
      - web
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "10m"

networks:
  net:
    enable_ipv6: true
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: fd02::/64
          gateway: fd02::1

volumes:
  db:
  static:
```

Potential users of my app could use this file to deploy my app if they first download all the source code from Github. However, I would like them to be able to deploy the app just by using docker-compose to download docker images that I have stored in my Docker Hub repo.

If I upload my docker images to a Docker Hub repo, do I need to create an additional docker-compose.yml that refers to the repo images so that others can deploy my app on their own docker hosts ?  Or can I somehow combine the build and deploy requirements into a single docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: You'd specify image with your docker hub image (username/image:tag) instead of build.

Comment: Thanks, so yes to having different docker-compose.yml files for build and deploy in this case?

Comment: Build by default also deploys but forces you to actually build. If you're looking for deploy without build, you'll need a separate one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [use multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) when you run `docker-compose` commands.  The easiest way to do this is to have a main `docker-compose.yml` file that lists out the standard (usually production-oriented) settings, and a `docker-compose.override.yml` file that overrides its settings.

For example, the base `docker-compose.yml` file could look like:

```yaml
version: "2.4"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  web:
    image: me/web
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    image: me/nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  db:
```

Note that I've removed all of the deployment-specific setup (logging configuration, manual IP overrides, environment files); I'm using the Compose-provided `default` network; I avoid overwriting the static assets with old content from a Docker volume; and I provide an `image:` name even for things I build locally.

The differences between this and the "real" production settings can be put in a separate `docker-compose.production.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "2.4"

services:
  db:
    # Note, no image: or other similar settings here;
    # they come from the base docker-compose.yml
    env_file:
      - .env_prod_db
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "5"
        max-size: "10m"
  web: # similarly
  db: # similarly

networks:
  default:
    enable_ipv6: true
    # and other settings as necessary
```

For development, on the other hand, you need to supply the `build:` information.  `docker-compose.development.yml` can contain:

```yaml
version: "2.4"

services:
  web:
    build: .
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
```

Then you can use a symbolic link to make one of these the current override file

```sh
ln -sf docker-compose.production.yml docker-compose.override.yml
```

A downstream deployer will need the base `docker-compose.yml`, that mentions the Docker Hub image.  They can use your production values if it makes sense for them, or they can use a different setup.  They shouldn't need the rest of the application source code or Dockerfiles (though it's probably all in the same GitHub repository).